# GWT JSNI method call failing, but there are no errors

Tags: gwt, mozilla, jsni

I'm trying to implement Mozilla's [Persona](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Persona/Quick_Setup) in a GWT App. Here's part of the code from a dummy app I set up to test it:

```
public class OpenId implements EntryPoint {

private native void callWatch(String email)
/*-{
    $wnd.navigator.id.watch({
        loggedInUser: email,
        onlogin: function(assertion){
            $wnd.alert("Calling method");
            this.@com.gallup.openid.client.OpenId::processLogin(Ljava/lang/String;)(assertion);
            $wnd.alert("Called Java Method");
        },
        onlogout: function(){alert("Logged Out!");}
    });
}-*/;

private void processLogin(String assertion){
    Window.alert("Logged in!");
    personaStatus.setText("Log In Complete.");
}
}
```

When I call the `callWatch` method, only the "Calling method" alert box shows up. Neither of the other ones are ever called. So for some reason the code appears to be stopping at the JSNI call right below the first alert. But there are no errors in Dev Mode.

I don't understand why the `processLogin` method doesn't get called.

I thought I followed [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI) correctly.

I did try writing

```
this.@com.gallup.openid.client.OpenId::processLogin(Ljava/lang/String;)(assertion);
```

as `OpenID.@...` and `instance.@...` due to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981924/native-javascript-method-in-gwt).

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Looks like there might be a porblem with the assertion varible... Does '$wnd.alert(assertion);' display a string. If so have you tried passing a static string to your processLogin function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `this` points to the function that immediately surrounds it, which is in this case your onlogin JavaScript function. You need to use a temporary `that` variable (a typical JavaScript idiom, by the way)

```java
private native void callWatch(String email)
/*-{
  var that = this;
   ...
    onlogin: function(assertion){
      that.@com...
```

And then, ideally use `$entry(...)`, so you will see error messages, if you have registered an UncaughtExceptionHandler.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235580/291741